# Python: Updating data in mysql using prepared statement

Tags: python, mysql, sql-update, prepared-statement, mysql-python

I'm currently stuck with a Python script I wrote. I tried to write it as general as possible to use it for other projects and integrations as well. Therefore I'm building an update statement on demand, which ends up with this:

```
import mysql.connector as mariadb

conn = mariadb.connect(host='localhost', user='***', password='***', database='***', port=3306)

cursor=conn.cursor(prepared=True)

sqlcmd = "UPDATE aix_resourcegroups SET aix_rg_current_host=%(current_node)s, aix_rg_dns=%(dns)s, aix_rg_cluster=%(cluster_name)s, aix_rg_ip=%(ip)s, aix_rg_label=%(label)s WHERE aix_rg_name=%(resourcegroup)s"

data={'cluster_name': 'mycluster', 'resourcegroup': 'ZUPSOAP', 'label': 'myrg', 'current_node': 'nodename', 'ip': '1.2.3.4', 'dns': 'myhost.anywhere.net'}

cursor.execute(sqlcmd, data)
```

The error is:

```
ERROR: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '%(current_node)s, aix_rg_dns=%(dns)s, aix_rg_cluster=%(cluster_name)s, aix_rg_ip' at line 1
```

I thought that using `$(key)s` might use the dictionary index and replaces the the tuple with the value of its key in the given dictionary.

It was working before using `?` (question marks) instead of `%(name)s`, but since I have to take control over the order of values to update (got once already rubbish in my table) I thought it might me a good idea to switch to named values (or however this might be called).

However, any hints for me to get this done? Also hints on how to get the full executed SQL command through the cursor might be helpful.

Many thanks in advance!

Regards, Thomas

Answer (score 0):

I think I can answer this myself.

I just tried to run the same statement without preparing and it was working like a charme. :)

So, the solution is:

```
import mysql.connector as mariadb

conn = mariadb.connect(host='localhost', user='***', password='***', database='***', port=3306)

cursor=conn.cursor()

sqlcmd = "UPDATE aix_resourcegroups SET aix_rg_current_host=%(current_node)s, aix_rg_dns=%(dns)s, aix_rg_cluster=%(cluster_name)s, aix_rg_ip=%(ip)s, aix_rg_label=%(label)s WHERE aix_rg_name=%(resourcegroup)s"

data={'cluster_name': 'mycluster', 'resourcegroup': 'ZUPSOAP', 'label': 'myrg', 'current_node': 'nodename', 'ip': '1.2.3.4', 'dns': 'myhost.anywhere.net'}

cursor.execute(sqlcmd, data)

conn.commit()
conn.close()
```